# Digikam: What's the problem?

Tags: ppa, kde, digikam

I installed Digikam by using the [Philip5-PPA](https://launchpad.net/~philip5/+archive/extra). When I run it I get the error below. This is by running it through gdb:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/digikam 
/usr/bin/digikam: error while loading shared libraries: libcxcore.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Inferior 1 (process 29894) exited with code 0177]
```

### What should I do to find the error and fix it?

I can see that somehow `libcxcore.so.2.1` is wanted but not found. Is this an error of the PPA, or can I simply point it in the right direction? Can I raise an issue with the PPA creator through launchpad?

Some next steps would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the digikam package which either needs to:

1. depend on a package which provides libcxcore;
2. install libcxcore together with the program.

libcxcore is not available in the Ubuntu archives. It might be available on that PPA, though after a quick look I could not find it.

> What should I do to find the error and fix it?

To resolve the problem you should either find a package that provides libcxcore or package the library by yourself.

> Can I raise an issue with the PPA creator through launchpad?

Yes, you should: the package needs to be fixed because either its requirements are not fully specified in the control file, or it doesn't ship all the required files.